# What's the Discipline cap?

Tags: dont-rest-your-head

So far as I can tell, Don't Rest Your Head doesn't say anything about a cap on Discipline. I'm pretty sure there has to be, though: with a cost of 5 Hope minus my current Discipline level to improve Discipline by 1, once I hit 5 Discipline I can effectively gain unlimited Discipline! That doesn't seem right.

Is Discipline hard-capped at 3, is there some other limit in place, or are we just avoiding letting this become a thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Discipline is hard-capped at 3**

Look at page 70 in the section of the Boss:

> keep in mind that a “maxed out” protagonist can bring a full 15 dice
>   to the table – 3 discipline, 6 exhaustion, and 6 madness.